# Function with variable number of arguments

Tags: function-construction

I am reading this page : https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsWithVariableNumbersOfArguments.html

And I don't understand the example : `h[a___, x_, b___, x_, c___] := hh[x] h[a, b, c]`

At the exact first call, which vales take x,a,b,c on the call ? Because I am confused with thoose ___.

Comment: In the linked page, there are explanations of those blanks right below this example.

Comment: A brief explanation: the two `x_` represents any two duplicated elements, and `a`, `b`, `c` with blank null sequence pattern can represent anything. Together `h` will pick out duplicated elements regardless of their positions. If your first call refers to `h[2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3]`, then `a` is `Sequence[]`(`Nothing`), `b` is 3, `c` is  `Sequence[4,5,3]` and `x` is `2`, the expression becomes ` hh[2] h[3,4,5,3]`. Then the latter part can also be matched, with `a` is `Sequence[]`, `b` is `Sequence[4,5]`, `c` is  `Sequence[]` and `x` is `3`, then the final answer is `h[4, 5] hh[2] hh[3]`

Comment: @happyfish I think the explanation in the reference might not be so clear. Why not post your comment as an answer? This question should be OK, IMO.

Comment: When you say h will pick out duplicated elements. Here we have $2$ and $3$ that have two occurences. How the function knows $x=2$ and not $x=3$ for example ? Is it the first duplicated elements that the functions meet ? Then as $2$ is the first duplicated, the program knows that $a$ has to be nothing ?

Comment: So you are basically asking how pattern matching is implemented in mathematica? I do not have an answer. But you can look up algorithms that are commonly used, e.g. Thompson's construction

Comment: I don't think I am asking that deep but just : how did you know that $x=2$ and not $x=3$ in this example ? Because if $h$ takes duplicates elements, we have two duplicates elements so how does it knows ? In fact I just want to really understand your first step.

Comment: I know this information from tracing. ReplaceAll seems to look at each part and try to match from left to right, but I cannot find an explicit statement in the docs. It is possible to construct two matching algorithms, which will find 2 and 3 first in this example respectively. Maybe you can wait for someone else to explain.

Comment: @happyfish and OP: in pattern matching Mathematica tests the shortest sequence for `a___` that will match. That's the empty sequence. Then `x_` is `2`. The shortest (and only) possibility for `b___` is `3`, but if we had `[2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3]`, `b___` would still be `3` and not `[3, 2, 3]`. Finally, after the second `x_` the last `c___` must consume the rest of the arguments.

Comment: Such pattern-matching behavior can be customized by wrapping them in `Longest` and `Shortest`. The links inside the documentation for these wrappers will give a more detailed overview of MMA's pattern-matching mechanisms.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP This algorithm does not work for a general regex matching

Comment: @happy are you referring to regexes in the context of string matching? Sure, in that case Mathematica demonstrates the opposite behavior.